# Create Azure Storage Account using Azure.ResourceManager.Storage

Tags: .net, azure

How can I create an Azure Storage Account programmatically using c# or vb but without using the nuget package Microsft.Azure.Management.Storage as it is deprecated.
All the code I am finding is using this deprecated package.

Comment: Did you try with [Azure.ResourceManager.Storage](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.ResourceManager.Storage/) package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the Nuget package you would want to use is [`Azure.ResourceManager.Storage`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.ResourceManager.Storage/).

Here's the sample code for creating a storage account taken from [`here`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/storage/Azure.ResourceManager.Storage/samples/Sample1_ManagingStorageAccounts.md).

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.ResourceManager.Storage.Models;
using Azure.ResourceManager.Resources;
using NUnit.Framework;
using Azure.Core;

ArmClient armClient = new ArmClient(new DefaultAzureCredential());
SubscriptionResource subscription = await armClient.GetDefaultSubscriptionAsync();

string rgName = "myRgName";
AzureLocation location = AzureLocation.WestUS2;
ArmOperation<ResourceGroupResource> operation = await subscription.GetResourceGroups().CreateOrUpdateAsync(WaitUntil.Completed, rgName, new ResourceGroupData(location));
ResourceGroupResource resourceGroup = operation.Value;

//first we need to define the StorageAccountCreateParameters
StorageSku sku = new StorageSku(StorageSkuName.StandardGrs);
StorageKind kind = StorageKind.Storage;
string location = "westus2";
StorageAccountCreateOrUpdateContent parameters = new StorageAccountCreateOrUpdateContent(sku, kind, location);
//now we can create a storage account with defined account name and parameters
StorageAccountCollection accountCollection = resourceGroup.GetStorageAccounts();
string accountName = "myAccount";
ArmOperation<StorageAccountResource> accountCreateOperation = await accountCollection.CreateOrUpdateAsync(WaitUntil.Completed, accountName, parameters);
StorageAccountResource storageAccount = accountCreateOperation.Value;
```

Answer (score -1):

I use the Azure.Storage.Blobs package

```
dotnet add package Azure.Storage.Blobs
```

Updated documentation can be found at the link below

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/storage.blobs-readme?view=azure-dotnet

Comment: `Azure.Storage.Blobs` package is for managing blobs in a storage account. The question is about creating storage account using .Net SDK.

Comment: Blob is a type of object storage solution on azure. Your question was poorly written